# How to filter information in the dashboard of tableau where has two dimension on it

Tags: tableau-api

I'm building up a supervisor scorecard on Tableau, but stuck on filter the supervisor.
There're few criteria that needed to be integrated into the scorecard. Eg. The employees' lateness under each supervisor will be taken into account that supervisor's performance. Also, the supervisor's own lateness will also take into account his performance. 
My expectation would be aggregating all the criteria in dashbaord, and filter supervisor's ID or Name to get his scorecard data.

Here is the sample of my data.[image]

Now i've completed all the employee level data. I created multiple worksheet to evaluate the supervisor's performance based on their employees' performance, and filter by 'SupervisorID'

But i'm having a hard time to aggregate supervisor's own performance into it.
If i filter by SupervisorID, the Tableau will still give me employee level data. I've tried to create a set to only put Supervisor inside in a single worksheet, but all I can think of right now is to filter by EmployeeID to get the supervisor level data, but in this way, i'm not able to get the information in dashboard because i was using 'SupervisorID' to filter the supervisor.

Any idea would be helpful for me. Thank you in advance!

I'm having a hard time to aggregate supervisor's own performance into it.
If i filter by SupervisorID, the Tableau will still give me employee level data. I've tried to create a set to only put Supervisor inside in a single worksheet, but all I can think of right now is to filter by EmployeeID to get the supervisor level data, but in this way, i'm not able to get the information in dashboard because i was using 'SupervisorID' to filter the supervisor previously.

Can anybody think of a way for this situation? Any idea would be helpful for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not filter by the role? This should show the same viz but with only the employees with "Supervisor" as the role.

Edit: I think I misread your need. It sounds like you want to show the supervisor with the total late mins for them and their reporting employees. I think that you might want to create a calculated field that shows the supervisor if the supervisorid is not null else show the employee name. In your example, this field would have lines 1,2, and 4 with "Johnny". You can then use this field in conjunction with your late minutes field. I think this may get you where you want to go.